# 'UIPastebaord.general.hasStrings' not working on iOS 14.0

Tags: swift, firebase, ios14, uipasteboard, xcode12

I'm offering a custom keyboard app.
I am checking'full access' with the code below to activate some functions. It's a valuable code I discovered through this site a few years ago. But I found out that the code below doesn't run on iOS 14.
UIPasteboard.general.hasStrings always returns false. hasImages/hasColors/hasURLs all return false. But it doesn't seem to be real. If you paste, there is a previously copied content or only ‘TEST’ is pasted.
'TEST' is for checking purposes and should not be printed.

```
let pasty = UIPasteboard.general
    if pasty.hasURLs || pasty.hasColors || pasty.hasStrings || pasty.hasImages {
        hasFullAccess = true
    } else {
        pasty.string = "TEST"
        if pasty.hasStrings {
            hasFullAccess = true
            pasty.string = ""
        }
    }
```

I am deeply reflecting on what I only found out about this. Also, I'm really sorry for the users who use my app. So I'm asking here because I want to solve it somehow. So, if anyone knows how to fix it, I'd like to let you know.

What I have done so far
Update ‘firebase’ and ‘realm’ to the latest version with ‘cocoapod’
Fix a problem after pod update
Try modifying the code continuously by turning on/off Allow Full Access in iOS settings
Google search…

Let me know if someone knows a better solution. Or, I'd like to give you a clue as to the cause of the problem. I hope that people who have the same problem will consider it together.

Thanks for reading this far. And I'll wait for someone's help. please.

Comment: Have you tried to check if there is more than only strings in your pasteboard ? I mean check only if it has strings?

Comment: I tried printing UIPasteboard.general.string but it is only returning nil.

Comment: try printing the `numberofitems` or the `items`. The first pasteboard item might not be a string.

Comment: check the `strings` value. it will return all strings in your pasteboard

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I tried running it now. It always returns 0. It returns 0 even when I fetch the item copied with the Apple keyboard.

Comment: And when I copy the image in Safari, it returns 0.

Comment: Even if items are output, only [] is displayed. Strangely, even if the code prints'print("\(pasty.string)")' right after printing pasty.string = "TEST", it returns nil.
However, when pasting into InputView,'TEST' is pasted.

Comment: I have the same problem, @Hoya you get any chance to fix it?

Comment: Hosny - Sorry. I haven't found a solution yet. I'm just temporarily bypassing the problem. But I am trying to find a fundamental solution. To not be afraid of the next iOS update. If you think about it together and find a way, please share it. I will do that too.

Comment: @Hosny I've found a working solution. The problem seems to be that viewDidLoad is too early to listen for the pasteboard with iOS 14...

Comment: @Warpzit you are right, when move it to viewWillApper, it works now, thanks!,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the same issue. Our current solution is to use viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad when checking for full access.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    // We need to check fullAccess after view has appeared in order for UIPasteboard to be available.
    if self.hasFullyAccess() == false {
        // Do whatever.
    }
}

public func hasFullyAccess() -> Bool {
    var hasFullAccess = false
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let pasty = UIPasteboard.general
        if pasty.hasURLs || pasty.hasColors || pasty.hasStrings || pasty.hasImages {
            hasFullAccess = true
        } else {
            // We test if we can put something in UIPasteboard, if anything we have access.
            pasty.string = "TEST"
            if pasty.hasStrings {
                hasFullAccess = true
                pasty.string = ""   // Removes string from pasty again.
            }
        }
    }

    return hasFullAccess
}
```